# cart create with Coupon_lines in woocomerce rest api

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

Coupon is not applied Input is

```
"coupon_lines": [{  "code":"new50","amount":"50","discount_tax":"0",meta_data":[{ "key":"coupon_data",value" : [{ "id": "691",code": "new50","amount" :"50"}] }]
```

And response is

```
{
"code": "woocommerce_rest_invalid_coupon",
"message": "Coupon usage limit has been reached.",
"data": {
    "status": 400
}
```

}

But the order is created.

Answer (score 0):

I think this small hack will help you. I remembered I had the same issue some time back so maybe this one will help you. You have to change some

```
 "coupon_lines": [{

  "code":"flash30",
  "meta_data":[{
                   "key": "coupon_data",
                   "value" : [
                       {
                       "code": "flash30"
                   }]
 }
      ]

}]
```

Then it's working code.